# Eclipse 2019-06 IDE not running code in macOS Catalina 10.15 beta

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-catalina

So, I am currently learning Java and I use Eclipse as my IDE. Since upgrading to macOS Catalina 10.15, I'm unable to run any of my code. It simply shows this error in the console.

2019-07-20 11:33:49.298 java[2843:200186] NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework.

When I installed Catalina my FileVault security was turned off as it could be a problem mentioned in the notes by Apple. And I do not know how to resolve this issue. If anyone can help me, I'd be glad.

Comment: The simple solution would be to report the issue to both Apple & Eclipse, so they are aware of a beta problem, then just go back to your regular work environment until they have fixed it.

Comment: That's not the problem why nothing works for you. I get the same warning but everything works as normal